# How can I migrate a Time Machine disk to being networked?

Tags: network, backup, time-machine, high-sierra

I've just set up an Apple desktop, and it occurred to me that I no longer need to keep plugging my time machine into my laptop. I've plugged my hard drive into my desktop and set it up as a hosted time machine server according to these instructions:

https://www.howtogeek.com/330288/how-to-set-up-your-mac-to-act-as-a-networked-time-machine-drive/

Problem is, when I try to start backing up my laptop, it tells me that Time Machine disk doesn't have enough space. Sure enough, my hard drive doesn't have enough space to start a fresh backup, but it also happens to contain years of backups of the same laptop.

Is there any way I can continue using the old backup DB except over a network?